# What trioboelectric materials create the best charge?

Tags: electricity

With developing the maximum triboelectric charge in mind: What roller and belt material combinations can I easily/cheaply buy at the local hardware store to make a Van de Graaff generator?

I've started with bed frame rollers/casters because they are wide and have a crown (curve) that will hold the belt centered -- but I'm not sure what thermoplastic resin they are made from. Anybody know?

I'll need to wrap at least one of the rollers in another material, but what? It would be nice to try PTFE/teflon tape on the one, but sticking it down is a big problem -- teflon rods and teflon adhesive tape are not inexpensive!

I may use surgical rubber or resistance exercise bands as my belt.

If you have built you own generator I'd appreciate your sharing what materials you easily obtained and which developed enough charge to jump 6" sparks off an 11" ball.

Comment: You can buy cheap teflon folio for the cooking. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Reusable-Teflon-Cooking-stick-guarantee/dp/B001TKYTMA . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.rmcybernetics.com/projects/DIY_Devices/homemade_van_de_graff_generator_VDG.htm

Actually we made one orselves along these lines using Lego parts and motor. The belt was a broad rubber band as used by postmen to keep together a bunch of letters. The belt is between two small glass or plastic cylinders.  Great fun for my grandsons.